# How Do I Change XML Prefix For WCF Client Request c#?

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, soap, xml-namespaces

Due to requirements from a web service that I have no control over, I need to change my ns prefixes from the defaults of "s" and "h". The service provider has provided a .wsdl file for my service reference, however, they do not appear to have an online wsdl  for metadata exchange. I have emailed them and they confirmed that the prefixes have to be specific values (right or wrong on their part, I have to make this work).

Can someone please tell me the easiest way to change these values? Is there something I can modify in Reference.cs? Do I have to implement some sort of message formatting logic into my requests to change the values just prior to sending out the request?

Every element in the XML has to have a prefix of a specific value (2 values total), or the WS will not accept the request and simply returns HTML in the response. When I copy the request captured in Fiddler, over to SOAP UI and update the prefixes to what they require, the request works fine when executed from Soap UI. I'm simply not finding any simple solutions to this seemingly simple problem for c# VS 2017 development platform.

Also worth noting, when I load the .wsdl file into Soap UI, Soap UI generates all of the ws operations and requests with the correct, desired prefixes that I need in my c# app. How does Soap UI know the exact prefixes to generate in the requests?

I need to modify this:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header>
    <h:FooListHeader xmlns:h="http://foo.foo.com/Hello" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <h:FooList>
        <h:FooStatement>
          <h:Title>Foo</h:Title>
          <h:Value>123</h:Value>
        </h:FooStatement>
      </h:FooList>
    </h:FooListHeader>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <GetFooRequestType xmlns="http://foo.foo.com/Hello">
      <MessageRequest xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <ConFooRequest/>
      </MessageRequest>
    </GetFooRequestType>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

To something like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:foo="http://foo.foo.com/Hello">
  <soapenv:Header>
    <foo:FooListHeader xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <foo:FooList>
        <foo:FooStatement>
          <foo:Title>Foo</foo:Title>
          <foo:Value>123</foo:Value>
        </foo:FooStatement>
      </foo:FooList>
    </foo:FooListHeader>
  </soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <foo:GetFooRequestType xmlns="http://foo.foo.com/Hello">
      <foo:MessageRequest xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <foo:ConFooRequest/>
      </foo:MessageRequest>
    </foo:GetFooRequestType>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Example c# code:

```
public GetYaddaYaddaResponseType CheckConnection()
    {
        Yadda client = new Yadda();

        var msgRequest = new GetYaddaYaddaResponseType { ConnectionConfirmationRequest = new ConfirmConnectRequestType() };

        List<Statement> statementList = new List<Statement>
        {
            new Statement { Name = "Yo", Value = "123" },
            new Statement { Name = "Hey", Value = "123" },
        };

        var header = new StatementHeader
        {
            StatementList = statementList.ToArray()
        };

        var response = client.GetYaddaYaddaMessage(ref header, msgRequest);

        return response;
    }
```

Comment: How do you get the format of *this*? Did you use svcutil? Something else? Do you use a generated wcf client? I need to see the code that gives you your current result. Your SOAP UI message does work with that service endpoint?

Comment: I added a service reference in my project and pointed directly to the .wsdl file on my c:\ drive. I did not use svcutil, I let Visual Studio handle that for me. See edit above for sample code that I am using to generate the XML result that I need to modify somehow (I mocked up the values so they won't match exactly what is in my orginal XML example (Foo stuff)).

Comment: Yes, my SOAP UI message does work with the endpoint. I can capture this request in Fiddler, copy it into SOAP UI and update the prefixes and it works. I also have confirmation from the web service team that the sprecific prefixes are required in the requests.